# Semaphore in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, semaphore

I've met some issue on using semaphore in spring mvc framework.
Here is my code

```
private static Semaphore sm = new Semaphore(1);
public String getOnlineUserList() {
    CommonResponse result = new CommonResponse();
    if(!sm.tryAcquire()){
        return "busy";
    }
    //do something
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    sm.relase();
    return "worked";
}
```

This is one test method of a @Service in spring mvc and it has been autowired to a @Controller.

As per my expectation, if I request this method twice at the same time. The first request will be suspended for 10 seconds and then return "working". The second request will return "busy" immediately.

The actual result is these two requests both return "worked" with 10 seconds time gap. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that your controller method is synchronized or something like that, preventing the two service calls to actually happen at the same time. Adding logs to the code would help clarifying what happens.

Comment: @JBNizet I've made further test. I set the sleep time to 1 min and add a breakpoint in method doService of SpringDispatcherServlet. I resume the thread  immediately when it goes into the breakpoint of the first request. But it cannot go into the breakpoint until waiting for about 15 seconds when I proceed the second request.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the semaphore, right? Maybe the browser is delaying the second request? I would use a unit test first, then use two curl or two separate browsers. The browser dev tools might also help identifying the cause of the delay.

Comment: you are right, the semaphore works as expectation in two seperate browsers, but it doesn't work in i make these two request in two tabs of one browser. strange

Comment: It appears the browser is serializing (waiting until 1 finishes before starting the 2nd) execution of the requests.   Since browsers are well known to pull bits and pieces of a page in parallel, it may be that it has an internal unique key on the full URL.  That makes sense for bits and pieces of a web page.  Why execute the identical URL twice in parallel when you'll probably get a `304 Not Modified` response for the 2nd execution (and use the cached response to the 1st execution).  This is what browsers do to make web pages run fast.